# Cloudfront caching with signed URLs-- does it cache the resource regardless of signature?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

We're caching some S3 bucket content using Cloudfront.  Our URLs to these assets are signed, with an expiration date of 24 hours after they've been generated.

So after one day our customers would need to hit an API endpoint of ours to generate a new signature to gain access to those assets.  However, we would like for cloudfront to cache those assets for longer than 24 hours, regardless of the URL signature-- that way we'll minimize cache misses from Cloudfront and the clients will get content quicker.  Is this possible and if so, what settings should I be looking at in Cloudfront / S3?

Comment: You can adjust the [cache key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/understanding-the-cache-key.html).